# How to create a graph or a radar in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, graph

I'm developing an application with Visual Basic. NET. How do I create a graph or a radar system that uses data from a `DataGridView`?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using and against which FrameWork?

Comment: I use visual studio 2010 ultimate an framework 4

Comment: Web application (ASP.net) or desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Some random code here [Draw a radar graph in VB.net](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_radar_graph.html)

Or buy something from [Dundas](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/winchart2005/RadarChart.html) or [Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/Gallery.ChartFor.NET.ChartGalleryHome.aspx) or [someone else](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/1663/ItemPermalink.ashx). Hint: radar graphs are also known as spider charts